# How to debug a Clojure web application in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, ring, cursive

I am using Intellij + Cursive and I want to debug a Clojure web application written using ring + compojure. I start the application in the Intellij terminal using lein and the ring plugin:

```
> lein ring server-headless
```

I want to debug this application using Intellij to set up breakpoints in the source code, see variables, etc.

But Intellij's Leiningen tab does not show a task with the ring command. Run configurations also do not have an option to run the ring command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intellij has a [remote debug Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html) that [can be used with Clojure](http://ohokgotit.blogspot.com/2013/05/debugging-running-clojure-application.html).

First add the following options to the jvm in the `project.clj` file:

```clj
:jvm-opts ["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5010"]
```

Where 5010 is port number to be specified in Intellij Remote Debug Configuration.

Then, in Intellij, go to `Run -> Run... -> Edit Configurations...`Use the + button and choose `Remote.` Give a name to the configuration, change the port to 5010 and click OK. Run the application using lein:

`> lein ring server-headless`

After the application is running, run (in Intellij) the Intellij Remote Debug Configuration you created. You will be able to setup breakpoints, run line by line, etc.

**Without Leiningen**

Another option is to drop leiningen and run the ring application as a Clojure Application in Cursive. You have to add a `-main` function:

```clj
(defn -main [] (run-jetty app {:port 8080})
```

`app` is the function where you define your routes and use as ring handler `:ring {:handler xxx/app}` in `project.clj.` You have to require `[ring.adapter.jetty :refer [run-jetty]]` and debug the file in Intellij as a Clojure Application.

Answer (score 2):

You need two steps:

1. Update your `project.clj` to pass extra parameters, like this

```
  :ring {:nrepl {:start? true :port 4001}      ;; <== Add this
         :handler com.mycompany.web/myhandler} ;; you should have this
```

... this should launch the web application in port 4000 and also an nREPL port for debugging, etc. in port 4001. You can check the [lein-ring documentation](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring#web-server-options) for more details.

You should see the following when starting your app:

```
$ lein ring server-headless 4000
[... some output omitted ...]
Started nREPL server on port 4001
Started server on port 4000
```

2. In Cursive, connect to the nREPL server as described in the section *Remote REPLs* in the [Cursive docs](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/repl.html). You should use either `localhost` or `0.0.0.0` in the host name and 4001 (or whatever nREPL port you used in the configuration in the previous step).

Comment: I was able to run as you described but Cursive doesn't allow remote REPLs in debug mode. I wasn't able to set up breakpoints in my code.

Comment: How to run the `lein ring server-headless` in debug mode in Cursive, so I can set up breakpoints? Maybe I can run it in a local REPL or as a Clojure application.

Comment: I didn't find a way to run a lein (ring) app in debug mode using Cursive, but you can debug ring apps (without lein) in Cursive using:  

    `(defn -main [] (run-jetty app {:port 8080})`. 

`app` is the function where you define your routes and use as `:ring {:handler xxx/app}` in `project.clj`. You have to require `[ring.adapter.jetty :refer [run-jetty]]` and run as a Clojure Application.